# Python PyQt6 resizing layouts QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm moving code over to the PyQt6 GUI framework.  And I'm learning.  But, I've hit a snag.  I can't set the geometry of a QGridLayout widget.  This code doesn't work, why?

```
class MainGUI(qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lc_wig = None
        self.mailboxes = misc.read_mailboxes()
        test = qt.QLabel('testing...')
        self.grid_main = qt.QGridLayout()
        self.grid_main.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 1000, 1000))
        self.grid_main.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.grid_main.addWidget(test, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.grid_main)

app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_gui = gui.MainGUI()
main_gui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

With the above code, I just get a small window with the "testing..." label placed in it.  How can I set the geometry of the layout?

Comment: Remove that `setGeometry` and use `self.resize(1000, 1000)`. You don't "resize" a layout, you eventually resize the widget (or window) that it manages.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Now I just have to set the layouts to the correct positions within the main window.  Not asking for an answer for that though.  Hopefully I can figure it out.  I'm 1 day in with PyQt :)

Comment: No, you don't have to set the "positions". Layout managers are exactly what their names suggest: they ***manage the layout***. You can set minimum sizes for widgets, or have some extent of minimum row/column sizes or *stretches*. The geometry of items (including nested layouts) is completely managed by the layouts. I suggest you to read more carefully the [introduction](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and play around with them in Designer to better understand them. Finally, remember that you cannot set a layout for a QMainWindow, you have to set a central widget and put a layout in that.

Comment: Note: Designer already creates a central widget on its own when you open a new main window, but you still need to set a layout for it. Read more about [layouts in designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Also consider reading more about [size hints](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-hints-and-size-policies) and [policies](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html), which are what Qt uses to know how a layout would set the geometries of all items it manages.

Comment: Awesome, @musicamante .  I brand new to this and have been reading and search enging'ing a bunch, but it's a lot to take in.  FWIW, I didn't just post willy nilly here.  But, I'm moving forward by setting a frame (as a central widget) to nest all my layouts.  All is going well so far.  Thanks again.  P.S. I'm not using designer.  Doing it the tedious way.